# Parsing document object to get Xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am parsing my xml to use a function

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException, TransformerException
{
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Esign.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    test t=new test();
    Document d=t.sign(doc);
}
```

but I need to convert the output ((Document d)) back to XML file .
how can I do that?

Comment: The standard method is to use an XSLT transform with an [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have been doing it.

```
 //After Document d is created.
 TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(d);
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
 transformer.transform(source, result);
```